# Which is more optimal for compiling python 2.7 programs to exe - py2exe or cx-freeze?

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, cx-freeze

I want to compile my python program to exe. I know two modules, with the help of which I can do that, they are py2exe and cx-freeze. Can somebody tell me the difference (Does cx-freeze have more features that py2exe because it is from an external source)? Which one is more common among python users? Which one works quicker and more reliably with python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between the two is that py2exe is limited to Windows whereas cx_Freeze is cross-platform and works on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, etc. If you are only planning on supplying your application to those on Windows then py2exe is a valid option. It also has more Windows specific features that may be of benefit in that case.

Comment: Thank you! That explained my question completely.

Comment: One more question, which one runs and compiles python files quicker?

Comment: I cannot say for certain as I have rarely used py2exe but the difference in performance is minimal. Some Google searches on cx_Freeze vs py2exe will get you all sorts of opinions if you're interested! :-)

Comment: Thank you! %) I really appreciate your help and opinion!